# Convert nested JsonObject in Java

Tags: java, json, quarkus

I am try to map JsonObject to the object using mapTo method. in quarkus. But when have nested JsonObject it's assign as null. Can some one help me to solve this.

https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/json/JsonObject.html#mapTo-java.lang.Class-

```
package com.abc.telemetry.dto;

import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;

public class TelemetryDto {
    private String clientId;
    private String commandId;
    private String deviceRef;
    private String telemetryAttributeRef;

    private JsonObject options;

    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    public void setClientId(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    public String getCommandId() {
        return commandId;
    }

    public void setCommandId(String commandId) {
        this.commandId = commandId;
    }

    public String getDeviceRef() {
        return deviceRef;
    }

    public void setDeviceRef(String deviceRef) {
        this.deviceRef = deviceRef;
    }

    public String getTelemetryAttributeRef() {
        return telemetryAttributeRef;
    }

    public void setTelemetryAttributeRef(String telemetryAttributeRef) {
        this.telemetryAttributeRef = telemetryAttributeRef;
    }

    public JsonObject getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public void setOptions(JsonObject options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    public TelemetryDto() {
    }

    public TelemetryDto(String clientId, String commandId, String deviceRef, String telemetryAttributeRef,
            JsonObject options) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.commandId = commandId;
        this.deviceRef = deviceRef;
        this.telemetryAttributeRef = telemetryAttributeRef;
        this.options = options;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TelemetryDto{" +
                "clientId='" + clientId + '\'' +
                ", commandId='" + commandId + '\'' +
                ", deviceRef='" + deviceRef + '\'' +
                ", telemetryAttributeRef='" + telemetryAttributeRef + '\'' +
                ", options=" + options +
                '}';
    }
}
```

In this method, I am using the json to object converter

```
package com.abc.telemetry.service;

import com.abc.telemetry.dto.TelemetryDto;
import io.quarkus.logging.Log;
import io.quarkus.vertx.ConsumeEvent;
import io.vertx.core.json.DecodeException;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;

@ApplicationScoped
public class WidgetControlActionProcessor {

    /*
     * this is the lister to the Widget control action events
     * after reserving action, this method responsible handle further processing
     */
    @ConsumeEvent("widget-control-action-feed")
    public void widgetControlActionConsumer(String message) {
        Log.info("widget-control-action-feed: Reserved widget control action: " + message);
        Log.debug("Reserved action: " + message);

        try {
            JsonObject jsonMessage = new JsonObject(message);

            // Get telemetryDto and send to process
            Log.info("json object: " + jsonMessage);
            processWidgetControlAction(jsonMessage.mapTo(TelemetryDto.class));

        } catch (DecodeException e) {
            Log.error("Can't process action: " + e.getMessage());
            Log.debug(e);
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
            Log.error("Invalid message type: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void processWidgetControlAction(TelemetryDto telemetryDto) {
       
    Log.info("telemetry object: "  + telemetryDto);


    }

    @Scheduled(every = "10s")
    public void we() {
    publishTelemetryToDashboard("widget-control-action-feed", "{\n" +
            "    \"clientId\": \"fgfgf1\",\n" +
            "    \"commandId\": 1,\n" +
            "    \"deviceRef\": \"emulator\",\n" +
            "    \"telemetryAttributeRef\":\"abc\",\n" +
            "    \"options\": {\n" +
            "        \"username\": \"nimrekha\",\n" +
            "        \"state\": \"0\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}");
}

}
```

this message come from front end. but to testing I was added scheduler to send data.

when I invoke this method the option field contain empty object.

```
2023-03-09 17:57:25,023 INFO  traceId=c02b65fa0aba9f68ee6ea84481d92689, parentId=d9dff4c54d0af324, spanId=5d326389ab863d8f, sampled=true [co.abc.tel.ser.WidgetControlActionProcessor] [widgetControlActionConsumer] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-3) widget-control-action-feed: Reserved widget control action: {
    "clientId": "fgfgf1",
    "commandId": 1,
    "deviceRef": "emulator",
    "telemetryAttributeRef":"abc",
    "options": {
        "username": "nimrekha",
        "state": "0"
    }
}
2023-03-09 17:57:25,033 INFO  traceId=c02b65fa0aba9f68ee6ea84481d92689, parentId=d9dff4c54d0af324, spanId=5d326389ab863d8f, sampled=true [co.abc.tel.ser.WidgetControlActionProcessor] [widgetControlActionConsumer] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-3) json object: {"clientId":"fgfgf1","commandId":1,"deviceRef":"emulator","telemetryAttributeRef":"abc","options":{"username":"nimrekha","state":"0"}}
2023-03-09 17:57:25,053 INFO  traceId=c02b65fa0aba9f68ee6ea84481d92689, parentId=d9dff4c54d0af324, spanId=5d326389ab863d8f, sampled=true [co.abc.tel.ser.WidgetControlActionProcessor] [processWidgetControlAction] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-3) telemetry object: TelemetryDto{clientId='fgfgf1', commandId='1', deviceRef='emulator', telemetryAttributeRef='abc', options={}}
```

Comment: It would be better is you add valid example to the question. Your class called `Test` has a constructor called `public TelemetryDto()`. Hard to figure out how many things that you modified manually instead of just paste a real example class.

Comment: Could you also specify your Vert.x or Quarkus version version? Using `4.3.7` of Vert.x just throws an exception instead of return null value

Comment: Sure. io.vertx:vertx-core:4.3.2 (vertx-core-4.3.2.jar) this is the version of the event bus.